# cannot allocate vector but my environment is empty

Tags: r

I found lots of questions here asking how to deal with "cannot allocate vector of size **" and tried the suggestions but still can't find out why Rstudio crashes every time.

I'm using 64bit R in Windows 10, and my `memory.limit()` is `16287`.

I'm working with a bunch of large data files (mass spectra) that take up 6-7GB memory each, so I've been calling individual files one at a time and saving it as a variable with the `XCMS` package like below.

```
msdata <- xcmsRaw(datafile1,profstep=0.01,profmethod="bin",profparam=list(),includeMSn=FALSE,mslevel=NULL, scanrange=NULL)
```

I do a series of additional operations to clean up data and make some plots using `rawEIC` (also in `XCMS` package), which increases my `memory.size()` to `7738.28`. Then I removed all the variables I created that are saved in my global environment using `rm(list=ls())`. But when I try to call in a new file, it tells me it `cannot allocate vector of size **Gb`. With the empty environment, my `memory.size()` is `419.32`, and I also checked with `gc()` to confirm that the used memory (on the `Vcells` row) is on the same order with when I first open a new R session.

I couldn't find any information on why R still thinks that something is taking up a bunch of memory space when the environment is completely empty. But if I terminate the session and reopen the program, I can import the data file - I just have to re-open the session every single time one data file processing is done, which is getting really annoying. Does anyone have suggestions on this issue?

Comment: Clarification: I believe it is ***R*** (not RStudio) that is thinking *"something is taking up a bunch of memory space"*. It is often sensitive to what (packages, code) you are using to import and process the data, please provide more information.

Comment: @r2evans I didn't mention the package or the code because it didn't seem to be really common (I couldn't add a tag for the package I'm using when I was posting this question) but I tried to put in a bit more information, if this still doesn't seem like enough information please let me know.

Comment: I have no idea where `xcmsRaw` is defined, so some more information will be useful. Does it require `rJava`? Is it using its own compiled C/C++ code? Does it have external library requirements?

Comment: @r2evans It's a function in the `xcms` library by Bioconductor that calls in raw data file and reads it. I don't think it requires anything else other than installation (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/xcms.html)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, and without knowing more, I don't know that I or many others will be able to help you specifically. Tracing the packages, [`xcms`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/xcms.html) imports [`MSnbase`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/MSnbase.html) which imports `Rcpp`, so one place to start would be for memory leaks there. *I have no idea if that's the best place to start*, sorry, it is a random not-very-justified remark based on a little bit of experience (not with `MSnbase`).

Comment: (In my experience, memory problems are common when `rJava` is imported, less-so when using external libraries either direcltly-linked or memory-leaking when somebody mis-used C++ code (linked-in by Rcpp, not attributable to any problem in Rcpp itself). Again, sorry, no direct answer here.)

Comment: If @r2evans's guess is correct and you have issues due to a memory leak you shuold be able to see that by opening Task Manager and checking the share of RAM currently in use.

Comment: I still couldn't identify where the memory was leaking, but tried using `rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))` instead of `rm(list=ls())`, and this seems to work. Thanks for all the suggestions!!